# How to mock NODE_ENV in unit test using Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to set NODE_ENV in one of the unit test but it's always set to test so my tests fails.

**loggingService.ts**

```
...

const getTransport = () => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    let console = new transports.Console({
      format: format.combine(format.timestamp(), format.simple()),
    });
    return console;
  }

  const file = new transports.File({
    filename: "logFile.log",
    format: format.combine(format.timestamp(), format.json()),
  });
  return file;
};

logger.add(getTransport());
const log = (level: string, message: string) => {
  logger.log(level, message);
};

export default log;
```

**loggingService.spec.ts**

```
     ...
    describe("production", () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
          process.env = {
            ...originalEnv,
            NODE_ENV: "production",
          };
    
          console.log("test", process.env.NODE_ENV);
          log(loglevel.INFO, "This is a test");
        });
    
        afterEach(() => {
          process.env = originalEnv;
        });
    
        it("should call log method", () => {
          expect(winston.createLogger().log).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    
        it("should not log to the console in production", () => {
          expect(winston.transports.Console).not.toBeCalled();
        });
    
        it("should add file transport in production", () => {
          expect(winston.transports.File).toBeCalledTimes(1);
        });
      });
...
```

How can I set process.env.NODE_ENV to production in my tests preferably in the beforeEach such that the if block in my service is false and the file transport is returned. I have omitted some code for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core problem you are facing is caused by the fact that once you attempt to import the file that you are trying to test into your test suite - the code within it will be immediately evaluated and the implicitly invoked functions will be executed, meaning that `logger.add(getTransport());` will be called before any of the functions like `beforeEach` have a chance to set the environment variables.

The only way to get around this is to use the following approach:

You will first need to assign the `process.env.NODE_ENV` environment variable to a const variable within another file. Let's call it `environmentVariables.ts`, and the following will be its contents:

```
export const ENVIRONMENT = process.env.NODE_ENV;
```

We will then have to refactor `getTransport` to use this variable as follows:

```
const getTransport = () => {
  if (ENVIRONMENT !== "production") {
```

In your test suite, you will then have to mock out the const file which will allow you to change what the `ENVIRONMENT` variable is set to. Note `../src/environmentVariables` is an example directory and you will have to actually define what the relevant directory of this file is. Additionally make sure that this is outside of the `describe` clause, preferably above for readability:

```
jest.mock('../src/environmentVariables', () => ({
  ENVIRONMENT: 'production',
}));
```

Your unit tests will then execute with the `ENVIRONMENT` being `production`.

Comment: Is there a way I can change the mocked environment returned  value for different unit tests. I would like to check if console transport was set in development and if file transport was set in production. Currently it seems I can only mock the environment once.I updated the `environmentVariables.ts` to have function that returns a value(This works well) and I tried `(getEnvironmentVariable as jest.Mock).mockReturnValueOnce("development")` but it does nothing.

Comment: Yes, you can do this by lazy loading the module that evaluates the module that needs to be mocked within a unit test and adding a mock before it. Such question should probably be raised as a separate question as it is beyond the scope of this one, I'd be more than happy to answer it for you there with examples.